# Javascript working with empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script, is-empty

I am working with Google Sheets.  I want to build a custom function that adds 5 cells together.  This code worked just fine:

```
function addData(a,b,c,d,e){
    return a+b+c+d+e
}
```

When I put the values: 80,80,80,80,80...I appropriately get 400.
The problem happens when one of the cells in empty.  When I have the values:

___,80,80,80,80 I get 80808080

80,___,80,80,80 I get 808080

80,80,___,80,80 I get 16080

80,80,80,___,80 I get 24080

80,80,80,80,___ I get 320 <--- correct answer

The function appears to add correctly until it hits an empty cell and then just tacks on the remaining values instead of continuing to add them.

I am very new to JavaScripting so I really do not know where to begin my research.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I asked this question before but I feel like this is more concise as to what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

you get different results because each column has different format
try to convert string type to integer
or let script like that and change the column format to number

```
function addData(a,b,c,d,e){
    return parseInt(a)+parseInt(b) +parseInt(c) +parseInt(d) +parseInt(e) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  When I tried the above code, it added all 5 numbers as expected.  When I emptied one of the cells, the result was a "#NUM!" Error.

Is there a way to look at each selected cell and set the value to zero if this cell is empty?